# Removing quotes from re.findall output

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

I am trying to remove the quotes from my re.findall output using Python 3. I tried suggestions from various forums but it didn't work as expected finally thought of asking out here myself.

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time

price = [];

while True:
    url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=ETHUSDT"
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    data = soup.prettify()
    for p in data:
        match = re.findall('\d*\.?\d+',data)
        print("ETH/USDT",match)
        price.append(match)
        break
```

Output of `match` gives:
`['143.19000000']`. I would like it to be like: `[143.1900000]` but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Another problem I am encountering is that the list price appends every object like a single list. So the output of `price` would be for example `[[a], [b], [c]]`. I would like it to be like `[a, b, c]` I am having a bit of trouble to solve these two problems.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the response from `requests.get()` as JSON, rather than using BeautifulSoup:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=ETHUSDT"
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

data = response.json()
print(data["price"])
```

Comment: Still needs conversion to `float`, as that's the main question.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @HeapOverflow how would I be able to make the price float?

Comment: @MightyGarhem https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+make+a+string+a+float+in+python (or read the other answer you got here)

Answer (score 1):

To get floats instead of strings:

```
float_match = [float(el) for el in match]
```

To get a list instead of a list of lists:

```
for el in float_match:
    price.append(el)
```